# Scroll to closest visible tr after filtering a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using JQuery to filter a `table` (calling `tr.hide()` on non-matching rows). The `table` resides within a scrollable `div`. The problem: unfortunately, on filtering the list, the user loses his/her scroll position every time.

Is there a clean way to

1. obtain the top row of the current view port before scrolling
2. scroll to the very same row if it is still visible after filtering
3. or, if the row is no longer visible, scroll to the closest neighbor row (above or below), which is still visible

Answer (score 0):

just add an anchor in the row you want to keep and go to this anchor after you filtered

Comment: What's the difference between scrolling to the anchor / scrolling to the tr if both would be non-visible after the filtering?

Answer (score 0):

Although it say's experimental, there is the element.scrollIntoView.  It does seem to be supported by most major browsers.  And you could always polyfill for those that don't.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Cool, didn't know about that.

Answer (score 0):

It would look something like this. I don't use jQuery enough to use it in my example, so I will leave that is an exercise for the reader.

```
var rowToScrollTo = null;
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
{
    // Find the first visible row.
    if (rows[i].offsetTop > scrollableDiv.scrollTop && shouldBeVisible(rows[i]))
    {
        rowToScrollTo = rows[i];
        break;
    }
}

// Show/hide rows

scrollableDiv.scrollTop = rowToScrollTo.offsetTop;
```